# A newbie learning RUBY: Needs to implement the wrap_array_elements method in class Formatter

Tags: arrays, ruby

Needs to implement a wrap_array_elements method that takes in an array and two args for the left and right side wrapping and returns a new array with a string containing the "wrapped" version of each element.

Example arguments: `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, `"<<"`, `">>"`

Should returns an array: `["<<5>>", "<<6>>", "<<7>>", "<<8>>", "<<9>>"]`

```
class Formatter

    def wrap_array_elements(elements, left, right)
        @elements= elements
        @left = left
        @right = right
        formatted_array = Array.new
        formatted_array.push(elements.map {|element| @left + item + @right})
        puts "#{formatted_array}"
    end

end
```

Comment: Your method does not return the formatted string.

Comment: You're pushing a whole array onto `formatted_array` so you get an array with another array as its element. You'd want to use `Array#concat` to push the individual elements onto `formatted_array`.

Comment: thank you for pointing where I should improve

Comment: @Newbie you included the problem and your code but there's no actual question. I assume that your code isn't working? If so, please include the error (if any) or the wrong output, so we get an idea of what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler than that, you just need to produce a new array from the original one with `map`.

```
class Formatter
  def wrap_array_elements(elements, left, right)
    elements.map {|element| "#{left}#{element}#{right}"}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, instead of using string interpolation like in javiyu's solution, you can use [`Array.join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
class Formatter
  def wrap_array_elements(elements, left, right)
    elements.map { |element| [left, element, right].join }
  end 
end
```